# Julia regular expression to make the next character uppercase

Tags: regex, string, julia

How do I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string? Using `\1\U\2` as a part of a `replace()` throws an error: `Bad replacement string`. A regular expression is preferrable, but other ways are welcome. This is what I would expect to work, but gives the error:

```
test_string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
replace(test_string, r"(^|\s)([a-z])" => s"\1\U\2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `titlecase` function for this like this:

```
julia> test_string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

julia> titlecase(test_string, strict=false)
"The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog"
```

For more complex cases you can define `wordsep` function or change `strict` to `true` (the default).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `replace`, `uppercase` and a regular expression:

```
replace(test_string, r"(^|\s)([a-z])" => uppercase)
```